# Jquery, Qtip2 - trying to get only a specific div from url

Tags: jquery, qtip2

When user hovers over a link a tooltip appears. that tooltip needs to be a specific div from that links url. Everything works good so far, except i cant figure out how to fetch only that specific div (#tooltip)

there will be many links on 1 page but as an example links look like this

> ```
>     <a class="ttip" href="?category=weapons&category_subclass=katana&item=1">link 1</a>
>     <a class="ttip" href="?category=weapons&category_subclass=katana&item=9">link 2</a>
> ```

and script is

> ```
>       $(document).ready(function(){
>         $('.ttip').each(function(){
>                var link = 'index.php' + $(this).attr('href');
>                $(this).qtip({
>                   content:{
>                           ajax:
>                           {
>                           url: link
>                           }
>                   }
>                });   
>          });
>      });
> ```

EDIT:
i tried couple of things, including as it says on http://qtip2.com/plugins

> Just like the jQuery.load method you can specify a custom selector
> after the URL, delimited by a space, in order to only return a
> particular sub-set of elements from the page!. For example:
>
> HTML url: 'myCustomPage2.html #table5' // Return the element with an
> ID of 'table5'

so if i try...

> url: 'index.php?category=weapons&category_subclass=katana&item=1 #tooltip'

...nothing happens. it just shows whole page.
basically, this url im trying to fetch does some queries from database and echoes them in div #tooltip.

Comment: show us where the div#tooltip is in your html

Comment: div is inside fetched page